# Removing program settings with nullsoft uninstaller

Tags: c#, nsis, uninstallation

I have a C# program that is installed using Nullsoft installer script and I have discovered that the program is littering files :) .

The program is using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save
```

to store settings. These settings seems to end up in a folder with a very nontrivial name like:

```
$user/appdata/local/$publisher/myprogram_Url_sad546a5s4d6a5sd1adsd6/$version/
```

So my question is: 
How do I find this name from NullSoft so I can remove the files?

A quick and dirty solution would of course be to remove every older containing the name "myprogram" but that would prevent having several versions of the program.

Comment: Is this your program? Do you have any control over the unique install id?

Comment: is 'myprogram_Url_sad546a5s4d6a5sd1adsd6' an actual example of the ID part or just random characters?  If it is a GUID, that is probably a Program ID from the installer, which should be available in the uninstaller for you to use.

Comment: You may be able to clean up these files for the current user (if you're positive they're not just trying to uninstall and reinstall your app), but not (reliably) for other users, since they might have been copied to other computers via roaming profiles. I lean toward [Raymond Chen's advice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/17/4948130.aspx) to just leave the per-user data. It's where the user won't see it, and .settings files likely won't take enough disk space to matter.

Comment: @Anders This is not my program but I do have access to the source code.  Where can I find this install id?

Comment: @SteveMitcham That was just random characters. Unfortunately it is not enough characters to be a GUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for files/folders with the [`${Locate} "$localappdata\$publisher" "/L=D /G=0 /M=myprogram_*" MyCallbackfunc`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#locate) macro and check in MyCallbackfunc if that folder contains a $version folder. You can also call [FindFirst](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#FindFirst) directly if you don't want to use a macro...

Comment: This seems like this is the best solution for now and I talked to persons in charge of the project and it seems like it would be ok to just wipe all folders with the name "myprogram*" since we will not support using several versions at the same time anyways.